# Mongoose + MongoDB can you query all parent collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have collections named using dot notation like so:

```
game.clue
game.checkpoint
game.business
```

Is it possible to query all "game" collections? `db.collection("game").find...` doesn't work. If not what is the best way to organize a simple hierarchy like this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just decided to make a "path" field that categorizes documents and put them all in one collection.

Answer (score 1):

No, that doesn't work.

In MongoDB a collection name is a string.  The period character does not have any special significance in a collection name.

"game.clue", "game_clue", "game-clue", "gameClue", etc. are equivalent ways to combine the name components.

There is no built-in functionality to run the same query in multiple collection.

You could use listCollections or getCollectionNames to retrieve a list of all of the collections, use a regex to filter them, and then run a query in each one.

Answer (score -1):

In Mongo 4.4 you can use $lookup to join the tables!
Here's a link for how to do it:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

A better hierarchy can really depend on your needs. It's hard to say which database schema would work for you.

I would store games in a collection and have it structured like this:

```
[
  {clue:{},
   checkpoint:{},
   business:{},
  },...
]
```

Again, it's hard to tell without knowing the data you're storing or the use case.